# Why do you think compliance test is important?

Tags: test-automation-framework

Now a days compliance test for any product  or service is becoming unavoidable. Provide some genuine reasons that can prove that is really an important job for any service.

Comment: Compliance with respect to what criterion? Standards, UX guidelines, browser compliance? Can you expand the term compliance testing you use?

Comment: Hi user3115137, I concur with dzieciou.  Can you elaborate?  Do you mean compliance tests, or testing for compliance (can be very different).  Also beyond, do you mean compliance to set standards such as PCI or documented SOX or ISO standards?

Answer (score 2):

Compliance testing certifies the product meets minimum documented requirements.

These requirements are available generally for broader group who may like to use your product assuming the product meets documented requirements. This group will be interested in checking compliance first. (and so it is important to have compliance report ready)

However compliance testing generally do not throw light on general software quality or defect density. You will need to plan normal test cycle for the product to ensure overall software quality.